# Javascript check if an input is a Long or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, long-integer, onfocus

I have this problem: I have an input field like this:

```
<div class="sigle-sz">
  <span class="label-sz">44</span>

  <input id="fillOrderFormEntries0.sizeEntries0.sizeValues5" 
         name="fillOrderFormEntries[0].sizeEntries[0].sizeValues[5]" 
         type="tel" 
         value="">

  <div class=" available wtqtn yes ">78</div>
</div>
```

and I want check if the value that user input in is `<=` of the *max Long value* or not. How can I do and when? I have to do this when the event `onFocus` change? I have to do this in Javascript, capturing the event and make the check.

Thanks to all.

Comment: I have to do this in Javascript. Why jQuery tag?

Comment: you realise HTML input fields support a max length natively, right? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input

Comment: How many characters can have a Long number?